# Ember.js : Modify request URL

Tags: ember.js

I create an Ember app with a Symfony REST api. I also use the REST adapter for my requests.

I have 2 models in my app : **users** and their related **comments**.
I already created CRUD operations for my user properties and now I focus on the CRUD operations for comments.

**`Model user.js`**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),

    comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});
```

**`Model comment.js`**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    message: DS.attr('string'),

    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

I have a route which shows all comments (and other data) of a given user. The request loads the user object and his relations. On the view I also have a form and an action to create a new comment for this user.

**`Route users/get.js`**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    id: null,

    model(params) {
        this.set('id', params.user_id);
        return this.get('store').findRecord('user', params.user_id, {include: 'comments'});
    },
});
```

**`Route users/get/comments.js`**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.modelFor('user.get', params.user_id);
    },
});
```

**`Controller users/get/comments.js`**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    newComment: null,
    user: null,

    init: function() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        let comment = this.store.createRecord('comment');
        this.set('newComment', comment);
    },

    actions: {
        saveComment: function() {
            let user = this.get('model');
            let comment = this.get('newComment');

            comment.set('user', user);
            comment.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works, except for the request sent to the backend. I loaded the comments from the user, so I expect a call to :

**POST** **`http://my-app.local/users/comments/`**

Instead the call is sent to :

**POST** **`http://my-app.local/comments/`**

Do you know why and how could I correct it ?

Second problem, the model is loaded from the 'user.get' route. This works because the user comes from this route to this page, but... It's doesn't work if the user enters directly the URL for comments. That sound logical, but I have no clue how to correct this problem... Can you help me ?

Comment: Route users/get/comments.js why did you paste this route here. It says nothing. Would be better to show the parent that is calling the data.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the post to add the get route.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by rewrite the `CommentAdapter.urlForCreateRecord` method. Which affect new comment record requests.

adapters/comment.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot) {
        return '/users/comments'; // the url you want
    }
});
```

There are several `urlFor...` method you might need to customise your url.
Just check out the document
http://devdocs.io/ember/classes/ds.buildurlmixin/methods#urlForCreateRecord

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I would like to understand the logical of Ember about that. Does Ember generate only

**`[POST] http://domain.ext/entity/`**

requests for creations by default ?

It seems logical to me that if I create an object which belongs to another object, I should have the ability to call a

**`[POST] http://domain.ext/parent_entity/{id}/child_entity`**

by default...?

Comment: As far as I know Ember does not really restrict what kind of API protocol you should use. By API protocol I mean URL format and data structure. It is your choice to make. But Ember did provide JSONApi and simple Rest adapter.

Comment: Just checkout how RestAdapter is implemented and try to extend your own adapter, you should be able to do whatever you want with request method, request url or payload data.

Comment: This is my TicketAdapter.createRecord method. I completely rewrite the request.
createRecord: function (store, type, snapshot) {

        var adapterOptions = snapshot.adapterOptions || {};

        if (adapterOptions.chatID) {

            return store.adapterFor('im/chat-api').doRequest('tickets.createTicketForChat', {chat_id: adapterOptions.chatID});
        }
        else if (adapterOptions.apiName === 'reopenTicket') {

            return this.doRequest('tickets.reopenTicket', {id: snapshot.id});
        }

        return this._super(...arguments);
    }